# What information do quiver gauge diagrams provide?

Tags: string-theory, supersymmetry, gauge-theory

I am struggling to understand what the information one can extract by looking a [quiver diagram](http://www.google.com/search?q=quiver+gauge+diagram) for a [quiver gauge theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/quiver+gauge+theory) is. I understand what quivers are but I cannot get some physical intuition and motivation for them. Is there a simple example in order to understand it? When I am looking at a quiver gauge diagram what am I trying to understand?